# Integrating Docusign Identity Verification (Phone Authentication) with an envelope

Tags: json, post, docusignapi, power-automate

I was using identity verification feature from Docusign with envelopes. Previously, envelopes are working fine without it. Then I enabled this feature and searched on the Docusign API Documentation, how to implement this feature. I got the necessary details like authentication token, workflow id. Try to hit the endpoint using Post request. Everything's fine but having issues in the body part of the post request getting invalid phone number response. Thank you for your time! Please help!

//Post request endpoint

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/f8594d59-9d52-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/envelopes
```

//header

```
Authorization: Bearer {accestoken}
Content-Type: application/json
Acces: application/json
```

//request body

```
{
    "accountId": "f8594d59-9d52-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "templateId": "4e2ba389-5d26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "emailSubject": "Please sign the contract",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "roleName": "Sender",
            "name": "Name",
            "email": "fName.lName@xyz.com",
            "identityVerification": {
                "workflowId": "c368e411-1592-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "steps": null,
                "inputOptions": [
                    {
                        "name": "phone_number_list",
                        "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
                        "phoneNumberList": [
                            {
                                "countryCode": "1",
                                "number": "8956324511"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "roleName": "Customer",
            "name": "cFName",
            "email": "cFName.cLName@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

//Response

```
{
    "errorCode": "PHONE_NUMBER_INVALID",
    "message": "Phone number is not valid."
}
```

//Expected Response can vary

```
{
    "envelopeId": "e8342cd0-ea2b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "uri": "/envelopes/e8342cd0-ea2b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "statusDateTime": "2023-01-13T05:22:35.0100000Z",
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.areacodehelp.com/where/area_code_895.shtml area code 895 is not valid.

Try with a valid phone number to confirm the issue, but to me it looks like the number you used here is indeed not a valid phone number.

PS
If you meant to use a number in Azerbaijan, you need to change the country code from "1" to "895" as it's a country code for a different country (the way you have is if for the USA)

Comment: Actually the phone number I used to display my problem was intentionally wrong but when I tried using my personal contact number with the correct country code it still gives me the same "Phone number is not valid." response. Just wanted to clarify that is there any issue in the json or are there any specific ways/format to write phone number in the string like I tried using "+1" in the country code, used masking as well "(999) 999-9999", It still gave me the same error.

Comment: Let me  look again

Comment: This is based on a template does the template have the SMS authentication set? or you are just adding it in the API call?

Comment: Yes, I have already enabled it before making an API call. 

IDENTITY VERIFICATION

Phone Authentication
Recipient will need to authenticate with their phone number via SMS or a phone call

+91 Phone number

Comment: I just tried it with number in India and it worked ok, but it has to be a real cellphone number, when I tried a different number - it gave me the same error. You must use a real phone number that receives text messages

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what I found is ID verification won't work with template roles because of the syntax compatibility. But it will work with composite templates, I made it work with composite template.

Additionally, both of the methods are compatible idVerification or phoneAuthentication. I am using idVerification for the first Signer and phone Authentication for the second signer

Docusign docs have more methods as well like sms auth, etc. Explore it from these links:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/

Check examples, in my usecase I explored Generic JSON Request/Response

Thanks for all the support from Inbar and the community!

```
{
"accountId": "f8594d59-9d52-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"emailSubject": "Please sign the contract",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "4e2ba389-5d26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "roleName": "Sender",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "name": "Name",
                            "email": "fName.lName@xyz.com",
                            "identityVerification": {
                                "workflowId": "c368e411-1592-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
                                "steps": null,
                                "inputOptions": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "phone_number_list",
                                        "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
                                        "phoneNumberList": [
                                            {
                                                "countryCode": "1",
                                                "number": "1234567890"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "roleName": "Customer",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "name": "cName",
                            "email": "cfName.clName@gmail.com",
                            "phoneAuthentication": {
                                "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                                    "+11234567890"
                                ],
                                "recipMayProvideNumber": false
                            },
                            "idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Note: Use valid phone number!